# When opening the keyboard on mobile, how can I force my content to shrink-to-fit to the available space instead of shifting up?

Tags: html, css, responsive

Consider the snippet below, where I've created a basic chat window.

**The issue:**
When you focus the input on a mobile device, the entire page is shifted up, pushing the header and messages out of view.

**The goal:** When you focus the input on a mobile device, the `#messages` section shrinks to accommodate the keyboard (similar to how the page behaves on desktop when reducing the window height).

(Images included below)

**My attempts to resolve it:** I've tried using `height: 100%` instead of `100dvh`, I've tried moving the height declaration to the `<body>` instead of the `<html>`.

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  height: 100dvh;
  width: 100dvw;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
}

#content {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#header {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

#messages {
  margin: -10px 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}

.message {
  padding: 20px;
}

#footer {
  display: block;
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 20px;
}

input {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="header">Header</div>
  <div id="messages">
    <div class="message"><b>John:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  </div>
  <form id="footer">
    <input>
    <button type="button">Send Message</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

[image: Example]

**EDIT:** Firefox on mobile handles this perfectly. Almost seems like Chrome and Safari are not accounting for the on-screen keyboard when calculating `dvh`.

Comment: Perhaps provide a diagram/drawing of what you want to happen. What do you mean by "shrink vertically"?

Comment: @GetSet Done! Added two screenshots.

Comment: I'd prefer a CSS solution but I'm willing to go the javascript route if I have to. Writing a custom keyboard to override the user's default seems like an absolutely egregious solution to this problem.

Comment: Thank you, but the answer linked there is 11 years old. I'm hoping that with modern CSS and the standardization of things like dynamic viewport units, there may exist a CSS-only solution.

Comment: The answer you linked is 5 years old, and it says "Just do this: <link to an 11 year old post>." Whether or not the 11 year old code still works isn't really my concern at this point. Again, I'm going to wait and see if anyone has a CSS solution to my issue. If not, then I will consider a Javascript solution.

Comment: To be clear, I never said I had any issues about the `position` attributes, nor did I call anything "old"., frankly I'm not sure at all where that comment came from. That said, I've now added an answer. In 2018, Chrome changed the default behavior for managing viewports while displaying the on-screen keyboard. The solution is revert to the previous behavior using `interactive-widget=resizes-content`. Old solutions aren't bad, but there are usually advantages to not being satisfied with the first answer you find.

Comment: Sorry, the above comment should say 2022*, not 2018.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code in the question is fine. `interactive-widget=resizes-content` to your `<meta name="viewport">` tag, like so:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, interactive-widget=resizes-content">
```

**Why:**

`dvh` units a re determined using the size of the *Layout Viewport*. As of Chrome 108 (Nov 2022), the on-screen keyboard affects the *Visual* Viewport, but *not* the *Layout* Viewport.

The `interactive-widget=resizes-content` forces Chrome to use the previous behavior, where both the Visual and Layout viewports are resized.

**Sources:**

[Chrome for Developers: Prepare for viewport resize behavior changes coming to Chrome on Android](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/viewport-resize-behavior#:%7E:text=Through%20the%20interactive-widget%20key,Visual%20Viewport%20and%20Layout%20Viewport.)

> In November 2022, with the release of Chrome 108, Chrome will make some changes to how the Layout Viewport behaves when the on-screen keyboard (OSK) gets shown [...] and instead resize only the Visual Viewport.

> If you want your website to use the pre-108 resize behavior, fear not. Also shipping in Chrome 108 is an extension to the **viewport meta tag**.
>
> Through the `interactive-widget` key, you can tell Chrome which resize behavior you want.
>
> Accepted values for interactive-widget are:
>
> - `resizes-visual`: Resize only the Visual Viewport but not the Layout
> - `resizes-content`: Resize both the Visual Viewport and Layout
> - `overlays-content`: Do not resize any viewport.

[image: interactive-content]

Answer (score -2):

I would of thought media queries would help with this:

```
    @media (max-width: 600px) { /* Adjust the max-width based on your requirements */
  #messages {
    max-height: 50vh; /* Example value, adjust as needed */
    overflow: auto;
  }
}
```

Comment: The issue is that on a mobile device (think phone or tablet), when the browser itself brings up its own virtual keyboard, which may push up content (visually). A media query won't address this.